# How can I delete this part of the text with regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a problem that I really hope that somebody could help me. So, I want to delete some parts of text from a notepad++ document using Regex. If there's another software that I can use to delete this part of text, let me know please, I am really really noob with regex

**So, my document its like this:**

```
1
00:00:00,859 --> 00:00:03,070
text over here

2
00:00:03,070 --> 00:00:09,589
text over here

3
00:00:09,589 --> 00:00:10,589
some numbers here

4
00:00:10,589 --> 00:00:12,709
Text over here

5
00:00:12,709 --> 00:00:18,610
More text with numbers here
```

What I want to learn is how can I delete the first 2 lines of numbers in all the document? So I could get only the text parts (the "text over here" parts)

I would really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: `^[^-]+-->\s+\S+\s` https://regex101.com/r/ZIkOdB/1

Comment: @zerkms Omg! thank you so much, it worked, I really appreciate it

Comment: @zerkms Sorry to bother again, but I just noticed that when I used that regex, it deletes part of the text, here's a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/baSyJJX.png

Comment: How about this then: https://regex101.com/r/ZIkOdB/3 `\d+\n[\d:,\s->]+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
^[\s\S]{1,5}\d{1,3}:\d{1,3}:\d{1,3},\d{1,5}\s-->\s*?\d{1,3}:\d{1,3}:\d{1,3},\d{1,5}\s
```

This solution match both types: either all data in one line, or numbers in one line and data in the second.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nKD0DQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution;

```
\d+(\r\n|\r|\n)\d{2}:\d{2}.*(\r\n|\r|\n)
```

Get line with some number `\d+` with its line break `(\r\n|\r|\n)`

Also the next line that starts with two 2-digit numbers and a colon `\d{2}:\d{2}` with the rest `.*` and its line break. No need to match all since we already are in the correct line, since subtitle file is defined well with its predictable structure.

Put this as `Find what:` value in `Search -> Replace..` in Notepad++, with `Seach Mode: Regular Expression` and with replace value (`Replace with:`) of empty space. Will get you the correct result, lines of expected text with empty line in between each.

[to see it on action on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pc7FEQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Subtitles, for accuracy you can use this:

```
\d+(\r\n|\n|\r)(\d\d:){2}\d\d,\d{3}\s*-->\s*(\d\d:){2}\d\d,\d{3}(\r\n|\n|\r)
```

Check `Regular Expression`, `Find what` with this and `Replace with` empty would do.
[Regxe Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WOsPkB/1)

`srt` subtitles are basically ordered. And it's better accurate than lose texts.

`\d` : a single digit.
`+` : one or more of occurances of the afore character or group.
`\r\n`: carriage and return. (newline)
`*` : zero or more of occurances of the afore character or group.
`|` : Or, match either one.
`{3}`: Match afore character or group three times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going for a less specific regex:

```
 ^[0-9]*\n[0-9:,]*\s-->\s[0-9:,]*
```

Demo @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZIkOdB/1)